# Error Message: Exception: Action not Allowed creating calendar event on someone else's calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function process(row) {
  var email = row[Header.EmailAddress];
  var startTime = row[Header.StartTime];
  var endTime = row[Header.EndTime];
  let approval = row[Header.Approval];
  let type = row [Header.Type]
  let message = `Your absence request about ${type} from `
      + "\r" + `${startTime}` + "\r" + `to ` + "\r"
      + `${endTime}` + "\r" +`${approval}`;

  if (approval == Approval.NotApproved) {
    // If not approved, send an email.
    let subject = 'Your absence request was NOT approved';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    row[Header.NotifiedStatus] = NotifiedStatus.Notified;

    Logger.log(`Not approved, email sent, row=${JSON.stringify(row)}`);
  }

  else if (approval == Approval.Approved) {
    // If approved, create a calendar event.
    if (row[Header.Type] != Type.WFH) {
  var start_datetime = new Date(startTime);
  var end_datetime = new Date(endTime);
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).createEvent('Absent', start_datetime, end_datetime);
       
}
```

When trying to create an event if they request has been approved, I get the error message: "Exception: Action not Allowed".

I have subscribed to the calendar and I am workspace admin.

I have tried to put in auth in OauthScope in the .json file but it does not allow me. The script works if I remove the row: CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).createEvent('Absent', start_datetime, end_datetime);